# mysql - combined join and union operation

Tags: mysql

I have two tables map and history

map has ID and region names

```
ID    region
N1    R1
N2    R2
N3    R3
```

history has a history of ID changes so old and new IDs

```
old   new
O1    N1
O2    N3
```

I want to append these two tables ensuring that old ids still point to the regions of their corresponding new IDs

```
ID    region
N1    R1
N2    R2
N3    R3
O1    R1
O2    R3
```

the only approach I can think of is joining the two tables, taking old and new from the new table and union it with map table. is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right regarding the union and join. Something like this should work fine:

```
SELECT 
    ID, region
FROM
    map
UNION
SELECT
    h.old, m.region
FROM
    history h Left Join
    map m ON h.new = m.ID
```